# Displaying videos in a Content Editor Web Part

Tags: development, content-editor-web-part

I am looking for a MOSS 2007 client side solution that will allow me to surface video links from YouTube etc for the purpose of presenting the most recent training content for the audience.  I am thinking a CEWP and DVWP can help here.

Right now,  I use a Page Viewer Web Part of the home page.  I need to update the link property every time with the current video link.  Not bad, but what about the archives?  Ideally I would like to have a LVWP that has the title, url etc of the archived video links.  Users than click on any video in the list/library and it is fed into a CEWP that is on the same page.

Custom development through Visual Studio not an option in this case.  I will need to be creative with Data View web part or perhaps connectable web parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a .dwp file you can build that will handle the displaying that Jaap mentioned.  You'll have to determine the click event story you want to use, but this will display any links you set up.  Just need to add code to query a List.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>SharePoint Videos</Title>
  <FrameType>Standard</FrameType>
  <Description>Use for formatted text, tables, and images.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>Left</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>3</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
  <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>
  <ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
  <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[<br>
    <div  align=center> 
    <SELECT  id=cancion onchange=document.all.music.filename=document.all.cancion.value;  size=1 name=Music> <br>
    <OPTION  selected>::::: Choose the Video to Play :::::</OPTION><br>
    <OPTION  value="https://home.sharepoint.private.massmutual.com/Documents/Office2007ECMPart1-DocMgmt.wmv"> Office 2007 ECM-Part 1</OPTION><br>
    <OPTION  value="https://home.sharepoint.private.massmutual.com/Documents/Office2007ECMPart2-DocMgmt.wmv"> Office 2007 ECM-Part 2</OPTION><br>
    </SELECT><br>
    <BR> <br>
    <OBJECT  id=music height=400 width=400 classid=clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95> <br>
    <PARAM  NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="true"> <br>
    </OBJECT> <br>
    </div> <br>
  ]]></Content>
  <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
</WebPart>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a CEWP with a custom jQuery script.

your jQuery script registers onclick event handlers on each item in the LVWP. onclick, you can then [insert a youtube video](http://haineault.com/blog/43/) inside a placeholder in your CEWP using parameters from the item you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also considered taking a look at the Podcasting Kit for SharePoint?
http://pks.codeplex.com/